# How to determine which row or control is making a DropDownList Read Data call

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a DropDownListFor control inside a Kendo grid, and I need the value of another element in that row in order to pass a parameter to the DropDownList's server-side read method. It's a similar setup to the example [here](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-to-send-values-to-my-action-method-when-binding-the-grid).

Here is the code which defines the DropDownListFor:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
.Name("LinkIdentifier")
.OptionLabel("---Select Form, etc.---")
.DataValueField("ID")
.DataTextField("Name")
.AutoBind(false)
.DataSource(source =>
{
     source.Read(read =>
     {
         read.Action("LinkTypeIdentifierDdl", "Alerts").Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("getCurrentLinkType");
     }).ServerFiltering(true);
})
)
```

And here is the javascript function which is called in .Data:

```
function getCurrentLinkType() {
    var grid = $("#linkGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var data = grid.dataSource.data();
    var dataItem = data[0];
    var valueForParameter = dataItem.SomeValue
    //--snipped for brevity
}
```

The problem above is data[0]. It only points to the first row in the grid, which won't be correct if editing any other row. If I use a javascript debugger within this method and look at "this", it's the AJAX call which is referenced, not the dropdown control. I can't specify ".Data("getCurrentLinkType(this)")" as the method.

So, how can I determine which row/control has made the call to getCurrentLinkType?

Comment: What you get if you add `console.log(arguments)` to the very first line of `getCurrentLinkType()` ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, I tested that and the only argument passed to the function is an object that contains a datasource filter object, which is empty, i.e. filter { filters: [], logic: "and"}

Answer (score 0):

There is no context passed from the Grid to the DropDownList to the Data function, so you need to figure it out yourself.

I have found 2 ways.

1:

```
// If your grid is single Selectable(), use the current selection
var dataItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
```

2:

```
// If your grid is not Selectable or is multi Selectable, get the row/tr closest to the editor and then get the dataItem from that
var dataItem = grid.dataItem($("#LinkIdentifier").closest("tr"));
```